# SCRIPTMANAGER from aspxdetailgridivew

Tags: vb.net

I am having a class B within class A in a form. I trying to call Scriptmanager from class B. But I am unable to succeed. Can anyone please, help me. Regards, Suma

Public Sub btnDisplayAttachments_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Dim btn As ASPxButton = CType(sender, ASPxButton)        'Used to access the sender's attributes through the control's command argument

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("x") = btn.CommandArgument

Dim str As Type = GetType(String)
Dim path As String = ("http://google.com")

Dim scriptstring As String = "window.open('" & path + "', '_blank');"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "script", scriptstring, True)
```

### End Sub

### The above method is in Class A.

btnDisplayAttachments_OnClick(btna, New CommandEventArgs(btna.CommandName, btna.CommandArgument))

And I am trying to call in detailgrid_rowcommand as above;

Thre are no errors. I can't see any erros on F12 either. I appreciate any guidance.

I need to open the "path" in another tab.

I am creating both master and detail grids dynamically.